# Bowling problem

Tags: technical-issues, kinect-sports

Hi:  When visiting my daughter, we play sports...bowling, in particular.  I seem to do very well most of the time, but once in a while, as I'm ready to throw the ball, it will stay floating in the air.  It is a frustrating problem to get it back and get it to actually go down the alley.
Anybody know what the problem is?  I  have tried being closer, going farther away, etc, but don't know what brings this on.
Please help.
G

Comment: Can you explain a little more about what is happening? Does it stay floating in the air while you're moving your arm back to get ready to throw, or when you're moving it forward to throw the ball? Can you actually get the ball back and throw it down the alley? Maybe that can help us tell you where the Kinect is having problems.

Comment: It floats after I have had my arm back and when it is forward to release it to throw down the 'alley'.  I can get it back and sometimes this is repeated and sometimes it goes down the alley, but I don't seem to have the same control.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate your error and could not.  I have a couple suggestions anyway.

1. When the error occurs create a large 'X' or 'Y' with your body.
   Kinect only uses a stick figure of you as the control.  I'm guessing that Kinect is confusing your head with your bowling arm/hand and that is what is keeping the bowling ball suspended in air.  Creating an 'X' or a 'Y' with your body will allow Kinect to recognize the difference between your head and both of your hands.
2. Make sure you have the Kinect
   positions in the ideal space.  While
   you can put the Kinect 2 feet off
   the ground the ideal position is 6
   feet off the ground.  Make sure
   Kinect has a clear shot of the whole
   play space.
3. Go through the Kinect tuner. See
   article [here](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/Live/EngineeringBlog/122910-kinect-tuner). This will help
   tune Kinect for your play area and
   give you some good visualizations
   about how Kinect sees you. 
   Understanding how Kinect sees you
   will go a long way to help you enjoying
   Kinect games.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  My problem is that my daughter's xbox is in San Diego and I am on the East Coast and can only use it when I am there, which I am not at present.  I'll try it when I go back there.  Thanks